# How to display images using node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a local server on port 3333 using node.js. My problem is that I cannot display local images. External images can be displayed. Can someone say to me if there is a solution to this without using Express? And if yes what would that solution be? All I'm trying to do is display an image but it's not working. Also is there a way to add a stylesheet to my code?

Using Express is it possible to load files with the existing node server?

The code I've tried to display local images(I've tried and other solutions, you can see in my whole code, no luck):

```js
res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,http://localhost:3333/images/top-band.png')
res.write(new Buffer(content).toString('base64'));
res.write('"/>');
```

And the whole code here:

```js
//include http, fs and url module
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    url = require('url');
    imageDir = 'C:/Users/Ionut/maguay/node/';
 
//create http server listening on port 3333
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    //use the url to parse the requested url and get the image name
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        pic = query.image;
  console.log(pic);
 
    if (typeof pic === 'undefined') {
        getImages(imageDir, function (err, files) {
            var imageLists = '<ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
            for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                imageLists += '<li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="/?image=' + files[i] + '"><img src="http://localhost:3333/' + files[i] + '"></li>';
            }
            imageLists += '</ul>';
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
            res.end(imageLists);
        });
    } else {
        //read the image using fs and send the image content back in the response
        fs.readFile(imageDir + pic, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");    
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
                //res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'image/png'});
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
     //res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
     //res.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css?v=123132'>")
    
     var pic_cuv = pic.replace('.png','.txt');
    fs.readFile(imageDir + pic_cuv, function (errc, cuvcontent) {
     if (!err) {
         res.write("<style>body{margin: 0; padding: 0;} #main-container{ margin: 0 auto; width: 1520px; height: 1000px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;} @media print{* {-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;}} #words{padding:0; margin: 0; display: inline-block;} #words li{ list-style-type: none;  display: inline-block; width: 33.33%;} #words li img{ width: 100%; }</style>");
         var threeWords = cuvcontent.toString();
      threeWords = threeWords.split('&h=250&w=1000&zc=0&q=100');
      
      //res.write(threeWords);
      res.write("<div id='main-container' style='background: transparent url(data:image/png;base64,"+ new Buffer(content).toString('base64') +") no-repeat center;'>");
       res.write('<img src="/images/top-band.png"/>');
       
       res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/images/top-band.png')
       res.write(new Buffer(content).toString('base64'));
       res.write('"/>');
       
       res.write('<ul id="words">');
        for(var i=0; i<threeWords.length; i++){
         //console.log(threeWords[i]);
         if(threeWords[i]){
          res.write('<li>');
           res.write('<img src="' + threeWords[i] + '&h=250&w=1000&zc=0&q=100"/>');
          res.write('</li>');
         }
        }
       res.write('</ul>');
      res.write("</div>");
     
       
      /*res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
       res.write(new Buffer(content).toString('base64'));
        res.write('"/>');*/
     }
     
      res.end();
    });
               
            }
        });
    }
 
}).listen(3333);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3333/");
 
//get the list of png files in the image dir
function getImages(imageDir, callback) {
    var fileType = '.png',
        files = [], i;
    fs.readdir(imageDir, function (err, list) {
 
        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
                files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
            }
        }
        callback(err, files);
    });
}
```

Comment: use this when your working only with images : `res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });`

Comment: Also, your code is hard to read. I'd first look if my browser is sending the pictures I'm requesting without using the code to make sure your paths are correct.

Comment: Why are you including an actual url as part of the data-url?  Everything after `image/jpeg;base64,` should be just the encoded data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind answering my question anymore. I've done what I had to do using Express.js.

The working code:

```js
//include http, fs and url module
var express = require('express'),
    http = express(),
 //http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    url = require('url');
    imageDir = 'C:/Users/Ionut/maguay/node/public/uploaded/';
 
 http.use(express.static('public'));


//create http server listening on port 3333
http.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //use the url to parse the requested url and get the image name
    var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
        pic = query.image;
  console.log(pic);
 
    if (typeof pic === 'undefined') {
        getImages(imageDir, function (err, files) {
            var imageLists = '<ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">';
            for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
   console.log(files[i]);
                imageLists += '<li style="list-style-type: none;"><a href="/?image=' + files[i] + '"><img src="http://localhost:3333/uploaded/' + files[i] + '"></li>';
            }
            imageLists += '</ul>';
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
            res.end(imageLists);
        });
    } else {
        //read the image using fs and send the image content back in the response
        fs.readFile(imageDir + pic, function (err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
                console.log(err);
                res.end("No such image");    
            } else {
                //specify the content type in the response will be an image
     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type':'text/html'})
     res.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://localhost:3333/css/style.css?v=2323243'>")
    
     var pic_cuv = pic.replace('.png','.txt');
    fs.readFile(imageDir + pic_cuv, function (errc, cuvcontent) {
     if (!err) {
      //I'm spliting the words by making use of "&h=250&w=1000&zc=0&q=100"
         var threeWords = cuvcontent.toString();
      threeWords = threeWords.split('&h=250&w=1000&zc=0&q=100');
      
      res.write("<div id='main-container' style='background: transparent url(data:image/png;base64,"+ new Buffer(content).toString('base64') +") no-repeat center;'>");
       res.write('<img id="top-nav" src="http://localhost:3333/images/top-band.png"/>');
       
       res.write('<ul id="words">');
        for(var i=0; i<threeWords.length; i++){
         if(threeWords[i]){
          //displaying the chosen words
          res.write('<li>');
           res.write('<img src="' + threeWords[i] + '&h=250&w=1000&zc=0&q=100"/>');
          res.write('</li>');
         }
        }
       res.write('</ul>');
       //name of the event
       res.write('<p id="event_name">@Eveniment</p>');
      res.write("</div>");
     
       
      /*res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
       res.write(new Buffer(content).toString('base64'));
        res.write('"/>');*/
     }
     
      res.end();
    });
               
            }
        });
    }
 
}).listen(3333);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:3333/");
 
//get the list of png files in the image dir
function getImages(imageDir, callback) {
    var fileType = '.png',
        files = [], i;
    fs.readdir(imageDir, function (err, list) {
 
        for(i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(path.extname(list[i]) === fileType) {
                files.push(list[i]); //store the file name into the array files
            }
        }
        callback(err, files);
    });
}
```